# NDK or OpenCV Camera crashing this app? Why?

Tags: android, opencv, android-ndk, android-camera

I'm trying to use native code to process some images using JavaCameraView class. Everything seems fine but when I run the app, it crashes with the following message: " it seems that you device does not support camera(or its locked). Application will be closed."

1. I already changed the build system to all devices but still get the same error.
2. Tried to use CameraBridgeViewBase instead, but the error messages doesn't change.
3. The permissions in manifest are all set

What could be causing this crash?

Here is the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.sample.myapplicationocv.MainActivity">

    <org.opencv.android.JavaCameraView
        android:id="@+id/java_camera_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

here is the Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewListener2{

    JavaCameraView javaCameraView;
    Mat matIn, mOut;
//    CameraBridgeViewBase mCameraView;

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("MyLibs");
    }

    BaseLoaderCallback baseLoaderCallback = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
        @Override
        public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
            switch (status) {
                case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS:
                    javaCameraView.enableView();
//                    mCameraView.enableView();
                    break;
                default:
                    super.onManagerConnected(status);
                    break;
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        javaCameraView = (JavaCameraView) findViewById(R.id.java_camera_view);
        javaCameraView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        javaCameraView.setCvCameraViewListener(this);

//        mCameraView = (CameraBridgeViewBase) findViewById(R.id.hello);
//        mCameraView.setVisibility(SurfaceView.VISIBLE);
//        mCameraView.setCvCameraViewListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCameraViewStarted(int width, int height) {
        matIn = new Mat(height, width, CvType.CV_8UC4);
        mOut = new Mat(height, width, CvType.CV_8UC1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCameraViewStopped() {
        matIn.release();
    }

    @Override
    public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
        matIn = inputFrame.rgba();
        mOut = new Mat();

        matIn = inputFrame.rgba();

        NativeMethods.binnarize(matIn.getNativeObjAddr(),mOut.getNativeObjAddr());

        return mOut;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        if(javaCameraView!=null) {
            javaCameraView.disableView();
        }

//        if (mCameraView!=null)
//            mCameraView.disableView();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if(javaCameraView!=null) {
            javaCameraView.disableView();
        }
//        if (mCameraView!=null)
//            mCameraView.disableView();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        if (OpenCVLoader.initDebug()) {
            Log.d("MAINAC", "onResume: OpenCV loaded successfully");
            baseLoaderCallback.onManagerConnected(LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS);
        } else {
            Log.i("MAINAC", "onResume: OpenCV not Loaded succesfully");
            OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_3_1_0, this, baseLoaderCallback);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the logcat output:

```
10-19 10:16:42.473 2501-2501/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
10-19 10:16:42.636 2501-2501/? D/CameraBridge: Attr count: 3
10-19 10:16:42.646 2501-2501/? D/OpenCV/StaticHelper: Trying to get library list
10-19 10:16:42.648 2501-2501/? E/OpenCV/StaticHelper: OpenCV error: Cannot load info library for OpenCV
10-19 10:16:42.648 2501-2501/? D/OpenCV/StaticHelper: Library list: ""
10-19 10:16:42.648 2501-2501/? D/OpenCV/StaticHelper: First attempt to load libs
10-19 10:16:42.648 2501-2501/? D/OpenCV/StaticHelper: Trying to init OpenCV libs
10-19 10:16:42.648 2501-2501/? D/OpenCV/StaticHelper: Trying to load library opencv_java3
10-19 10:16:42.649 2501-2501/? D/OpenCV/StaticHelper: Library opencv_java3 loaded
10-19 10:16:42.649 2501-2501/? D/OpenCV/StaticHelper: First attempt to load libs is OK
10-19 10:16:42.653 2501-2501/? I/OpenCV/StaticHelper: General configuration for OpenCV 3.1.0 =====================================
10-19 10:16:42.653 2501-2501/? I/OpenCV/StaticHelper:   Version control:               3.1.0
10-19 10:16:42.653 2501-2501/? I/OpenCV/StaticHelper:   Platform:
10-19 10:16:42.653 2501-2501/? I/OpenCV/StaticHelper:     Host:                        Darwin 15.0.0 x86_64
10-19 10:16:42.653 2501-2501/? I/OpenCV/StaticHelper:     Target:                      Android 1 i686
10-19 10:16:42.653 2501-2501/? I/OpenCV/StaticHelper:     CMake:                       3.3.2
10-19 10:16:42.653 2501-2501/? I/OpenCV/StaticHelper:     CMake generator:             Ninja
10-19 10:16:42.653 2501-2501/? I/OpenCV/StaticHelper:     CMake build tool:            /usr/local/bin/ninja
10-19 10:16:42.653 2501-2501/? I/OpenCV/StaticHelper:     Configuration:               Release
10-19 10:16:42.653 2501-2501/? I/OpenCV/StaticHelper:   C/C++:
10-19 10:16:42.653 2501-2501/? I/OpenCV/StaticHelper:     Built as dynamic libs?:      NO
10-19 10:16:42.653 2501-2501/? I/OpenCV/StaticHelper:     C++ Compiler:                /usr/local/bin/ccache /opt/android/android-ndk-r10e/toolchains/x86-4.8/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/i686-linux-android-g++ (ver 4.8)
10-19 10:16:42.653 2501-2501/? I/OpenCV/StaticHelper:     C++ flags (Release):         -fexceptions -frtti -fpic --sysroot=/opt/android/android-ndk-r10e/platforms/android-9/arch-x86 -funwind-tables -funswitch-loops -finline-limit=300 -fsigned-char -no-canonical-prefixes -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -Wa,--noexecstack    -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -fdiagnostics-show-option -march=i686 -fomit-frame-pointer -msse -msse2 -mno-avx -msse3 -mno-ssse3 -mno-sse4.1 -mno-sse4.2 -mfpmath=sse -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -fomit-frame-pointer -fstrict-aliasing -O2 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
10-19 10:16:42.653 2501-2501/? I/OpenCV/StaticHelper:     C++ flags (Debug):           -fexceptions -frtti -fpic --sysroot=/opt/android/android-ndk-r10e/platforms/android-9/arch-x86 -funwind-tables -funswitch-loops -finline-limit=300 -fsigned-char -no-canonical-prefixes -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -Wa,--noexecstack    -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -fdiagnostics-show-option -march=i686 -fomit-frame-pointer -msse -msse2 -mno-avx -msse3 -mno-ssse3 -mno-sse4.1 -mno-sse4.2 -mfpmath=sse -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing -O0 -g -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
10-19 10:16:42.653 2501-2501/? I/OpenCV/StaticHelper:     C Compiler:                  /usr/local/bin/ccache /opt/android/android-ndk-r10e/toolchains/x86-4.8/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/i686-linux-android-gcc
10-19 10:16:42.653 2501-2501/? I/OpenCV/StaticHelper:     C flags (Release):           -fexceptions -fpic --sysroot=/opt/android/android-ndk-r10e/platforms/android-9/arch-x86 -funwind-tables -funswitch-loops -finline-limit=300 -fsigned-char -no-canonical-prefixes -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -Wa,--noexecstack    -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wno-narrowing -fdiagnostics-show-option -march=i686 -fomit-frame-pointer -msse -msse2 -mno-avx -msse3 -mno-ssse3 -mno-sse4.1 -mno-sse4.2 -mfpmath=sse -fvisibility=hidden -fomit-frame-pointer -fstrict-aliasing -O2 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
10-19 10:16:42.653 2501-2501/? I/OpenCV/StaticHelper:     C flags (Debug):             -fexceptions -fpic --sysroot=/opt/android/android-ndk-r10e/platforms/android-9/arch-x86 -funwind-tables -funswitch-loops -finline-limit=300 -fsigned-char -no-canonical-prefixes -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -Wa,--noexecstack    -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wno-narrowing -fdiagnostics-show-option -march=i686 -fomit-frame-pointer -msse -msse2 -mno-avx -msse3 -mno-ssse3 -mno-sse4.1 -mno-sse4.2 -mfpmath=sse -fvisibility=hidden -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing -O0 -g -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
10-19 10:16:42.653 2501-2501/? I/OpenCV/StaticHelper:     Linker flags (Release):      -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now 
10-19 10:16:42.653 2501-2501/? I/OpenCV/StaticHelper:     Linker flags (Debug):        -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now 
10-19 10:16:42.653 2501-2501/? I/OpenCV/StaticHelper:     Precompiled headers:         NO
10-19 10:16:42.653 2501-2501/? I/OpenCV/StaticHelper:     Extra dependencies:          z dl m log
10-19 10:16:42.653 2501-2501/? I/OpenCV/StaticHelper:     3rdparty dependencies:       libjpeg libwebp libpng libtiff libjasper IlmImf tbb
10-19 10:16:42.653 2501-2501/? I/OpenCV/StaticHelper:   OpenCV modules:
10-19 10:16:42.653 2501-2501/? I/OpenCV/StaticHelper:     To be built:                 core flann imgproc ml photo video imgcodecs shape videoio highgui objdetect superres features2d calib3d java stitching videostab
10-19 10:16:42.653 2501-2501/? I/OpenCV/StaticHelper:     Disabled:                    world
10-19 10:16:42.653 2501-2501/? I/OpenCV/StaticHelper:     Disabled by dependency:      -
10-19 10:16:42.653 2501-2501/? I/OpenCV/StaticHelper:     Unavailable:                 cudaarithm cudabgsegm cudacodec cudafeatures2d cudafilters cudaimgproc cudalegacy cudaobjdetect cudaoptflow cudastereo cudawarping cudev python2 ts viz
10-19 10:16:42.653 2501-2501/? I/OpenCV/StaticHelper:   Android: 
10-19 10:16:42.653 2501-2501/? I/OpenCV/StaticHelper:     Android ABI:                 x86
10-19 10:16:42.653 2501-2501/? I/OpenCV/StaticHelper:     STL type:                    gnustl_static
10-19 10:16:42.653 2501-2501/? I/OpenCV/StaticHelper:     Native API level:            android-9
10-19 10:16:42.653 2501-2501/? I/OpenCV/StaticHelper:     SDK target:                  android-14
10-19 10:16:42.653 2501-2501/? I/OpenCV/StaticHelper:     Android NDK:                 /opt/android/android-ndk-r10e (toolchain: x86-4.8)
10-19 10:16:42.653 2501-2501/? I/OpenCV/StaticHelper:     android tool:                /opt/android/android-sdk-macosx/tools/android (Android SDK Tools, revision 24.1.2.)
10-19 10:16:42.653 2501-2501/? I/OpenCV/StaticHelper:     Google Play manager:         NO
10-19 10:16:42.653 2501-2501/? I/OpenCV/StaticHelper:     Android examples:            YES
10-19 10:16:42.653 2501-2501/? I/OpenCV/StaticHelper:   GUI: 
10-19 10:16:42.653 2501-2501/? I/OpenCV/StaticHelper:     GTK+:                        NO
10-19 10:16:42.653 2501-2501/? I/OpenCV/StaticHelper:     GThread :                    NO
10-19 10:16:42.653 2501-2501/? I/OpenCV/StaticHelper:     GtkGlExt:                    NO
10-19 10:16:42.653 2501-2501/? I/OpenCV/StaticHelper:     OpenGL support:              NO
10-19 10:16:42.653 2501-2501/? I/OpenCV/StaticHelper:     VTK support:                 NO
10-19 10:16:42.653 2501-2501/? I/OpenCV/StaticHelper:   Media I/O: 
10-19 10:16:42.653 2501-2501/? I/OpenCV/StaticHelper:     ZLib:                        z (ver 1.2.3)
10-19 10:16:42.653 2501-2501/? I/OpenCV/StaticHelper:     JPEG:                        build (ver 90)
10-19 10:16:42.653 2501-2501/? I/OpenCV/StaticHelper:     WEBP:                        build (ver 0.3.1)
10-19 10:16:42.653 2501-2501/? I/OpenCV/StaticHelper:     PNG:                         build (ver 1.6.19)
10-19 10:16:42.653 2501-2501/? I/OpenCV/StaticHelper:     TIFF:                        build (ver 42 - 4.0.2)
10-19 10:16:42.653 2501-2501/? I/OpenCV/StaticHelper:     JPEG 2000:                   build (ver 1.900.1)
10-19 10:16:42.653 2501-2501/? I/OpenCV/StaticHelper:     OpenEXR:                     build (ver 1.7.1)
10-19 10:16:42.653 2501-2501/? I/OpenCV/StaticHelper:     GDAL:                        NO
10-19 10:16:42.653 2501-2501/? I/OpenCV/StaticHelper:   Video I/O:
10-19 10:16:42.653 2501-2501/? I/OpenCV/StaticHelper:   Parallel framework:            TBB (ver 4.3 interface 8002)
10-19 10:16:42.653 2501-2501/? I/OpenCV/StaticHelper:   Other third-party libraries:
10-19 10:16:42.653 2501-2501/? I/OpenCV/StaticHelper:     Use IPP:                     NO
10-19 10:16:42.653 2501-2501/? I/OpenCV/StaticHelper:     Use IPP Async:               NO
10-19 10:16:42.653 2501-2501/? I/OpenCV/StaticHelper:     Use Eigen:                   NO
10-19 10:16:42.653 2501-2501/? I/OpenCV/StaticHelper:     Use Cuda:                    NO
10-19 10:16:42.653 2501-2501/? I/OpenCV/StaticHelper:     Use OpenCL:                  NO
10-19 10:16:42.653 2501-2501/? I/OpenCV/StaticHelper:     Use custom HAL:              NO
10-19 10:16:42.653 2501-2501/? I/OpenCV/StaticHelper:   Python 2:
10-19 10:16:42.653 2501-2501/? I/OpenCV/StaticHelper:     Interpreter:                 /opt/pythonenv/build/bin/python2.7 (ver 2.7.10)
10-19 10:16:42.653 2501-2501/? I/OpenCV/StaticHelper:   Python 3:
10-19 10:16:42.653 2501-2501/? I/OpenCV/StaticHelper:     Interpreter:                 NO
10-19 10:16:42.653 2501-2501/? I/OpenCV/StaticHelper:   Python (for build):            /opt/pythonenv/build/bin/python2.7
10-19 10:16:42.653 2501-2501/? I/OpenCV/StaticHelper:   Java:
10-19 10:16:42.653 2501-2501/? I/OpenCV/StaticHelper:     ant:                         /usr/local/bin/ant (ver 1.9.4)
10-19 10:16:42.653 2501-2501/? I/OpenCV/StaticHelper:     Java wrappers:               YES
10-19 10:16:42.653 2501-2501/? I/OpenCV/StaticHelper:     Java tests:                  NO
10-19 10:16:42.653 2501-2501/? I/OpenCV/StaticHelper:   Matlab:                        NO
10-19 10:16:42.653 2501-2501/? I/OpenCV/StaticHelper:   Tests and samples:
10-19 10:16:42.653 2501-2501/? I/OpenCV/StaticHelper:     Tests:                       NO
10-19 10:16:42.653 2501-2501/? I/OpenCV/StaticHelper:     Performance tests:           NO
10-19 10:16:42.653 2501-2501/? I/OpenCV/StaticHelper:     C/C++ Examples:              NO
10-19 10:16:42.653 2501-2501/? I/OpenCV/StaticHelper:   Install path:                  /Volumes/Linux/builds/master_pack-android/build/o4a/install
10-19 10:16:42.653 2501-2501/? I/OpenCV/StaticHelper:   cvconfig.h is in:              /Volumes/Linux/builds/master_pack-android/build/o4a
10-19 10:16:42.653 2501-2501/? I/OpenCV/StaticHelper: -----------------------------------------------------------------
10-19 10:16:42.653 2501-2501/? D/MAINAC: onResume: OpenCV loaded successfully
10-19 10:16:42.653 2501-2501/? D/CameraBridge: call checkCurrentState
10-19 10:16:42.668 2501-2514/? D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
10-19 10:16:42.810 2501-2514/? D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
10-19 10:16:42.811 2501-2514/? D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
10-19 10:16:42.818 2501-2514/? D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so

                                         [ 10-19 10:16:42.824  2501: 2514 D/         ]
                                         HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xeeb12730, tid 2514
10-19 10:16:42.850 2501-2514/? I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
10-19 10:16:42.962 2501-2514/? W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
10-19 10:16:42.962 2501-2514/? W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xf2cfd3c0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
10-19 10:16:43.259 2501-2501/? D/CameraBridge: call surfaceChanged event
10-19 10:16:43.259 2501-2501/? D/CameraBridge: call checkCurrentState
10-19 10:16:43.259 2501-2501/? D/CameraBridge: call processExitState: 0
10-19 10:16:43.260 2501-2501/? D/CameraBridge: call processEnterState: 1
10-19 10:16:43.260 2501-2501/? D/CameraBridge: call onEnterStartedState
10-19 10:16:43.260 2501-2501/? D/JavaCameraView: Connecting to camera
10-19 10:16:43.260 2501-2501/? D/JavaCameraView: Initialize java camera
10-19 10:16:43.260 2501-2501/? D/JavaCameraView: Trying to open camera with old open()
10-19 10:16:43.265 2501-2501/? W/CameraBase: An error occurred while connecting to camera: 0
10-19 10:16:43.265 2501-2501/? E/JavaCameraView: Camera is not available (in use or does not exist): Fail to connect to camera service
10-19 10:16:43.266 2501-2501/? D/JavaCameraView: Trying to open camera with new open(0)
10-19 10:16:43.268 2501-2501/? W/CameraBase: An error occurred while connecting to camera: 0
10-19 10:16:43.268 2501-2501/? E/JavaCameraView: Camera #0failed to open: Fail to connect to camera service
10-19 10:16:43.268 2501-2501/? D/JavaCameraView: Trying to open camera with new open(1)
10-19 10:16:43.269 2501-2501/? W/CameraBase: An error occurred while connecting to camera: 1
10-19 10:16:43.269 2501-2501/? E/JavaCameraView: Camera #1failed to open: Fail to connect to camera service
10-19 10:16:43.494 2501-2501/com.sample.myapplicationocv I/Choreographer: Skipped 45 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
10-19 10:16:43.961 2501-2514/com.sample.myapplicationocv W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
10-19 10:16:43.961 2501-2514/com.sample.myapplicationocv W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xeeb13e40, error=EGL_SUCCESS
10-19 11:47:11.404 2501-2506/com.sample.myapplicationocv W/art: Suspending all threads took: 7.478ms
```

Comment: Do you have Camera permissions in your `AndroidManifest.xml`?

Comment: Yes, permissions were all set.

Comment: Maybe your device is not compatible with OpenCV. Try to run their sample app https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.opencv.samples.puzzle15.

Answer (score 1):

As of Android 6.0 (API level 23), you must request permission from the user before you have access to certain functionality in the phone including the use of sensors and reading / writing to external storage. So to fix your issue, you need to request permission in the android manifest like this:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.app.myapp"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="true" />
...
```

If you are still having issues, then you can request for permissions at run-time. Here is how you do it:

```
String s = "CAMERA";
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    if (!hasPermissionInManifest(getBaseContext(), s)) {
        if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

For more details on requesting for permissions from the user, you can check out the [Android Developer](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) website.

Edit: fix typo in code